# Match one string against another string that contains regex

Tags: php, regex

I have two strings:

```
$relativeUrl = "/string1/(\d+)/string2/(\d+)/string3";
$currentUrl  = "/string1/1234/string2/5678/string3";
```

I am trying to assert that the `$currentUrl` does indeed match `$relativeUrl` which contains regexes for two numbers (`(\d+)`). The result I want is simply a `true` or `false` value.

I have tried using `preg_quote()` because:

> preg_quote() takes str and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax. **This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters**.

However, I have to [pre|ap]pend the delimiters in order to not receive the `Unknown modifier '\'` error and even then, I just get an empty array back. I'm not sure how else is best to go about this.

```
preg_match("^" . preg_quote($relativeUrl) . "^", $currentUrl, $matches);

var_dump($matches); // Gives array(0) { }
```

Am I going about this the right way? How can I achieve what I require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `preg_match` without `preg_quote`:

```
preg_match('#' . $relativeUrl . '#', $currentUrl, $matches);
```

Comment: Have you tested this? It doesn't work. I still get an empty array. [3v4l](http://3v4l.org/Nrp9M).

Comment: That works great, thanks. Looks like I didn't need the `preg_quote()` at all. I'll accept in 7 minutes... :-)